# jquery validation method for CVV number

Tags: jquery

I am using authorize.net {aim} for my payment gateway.

But my client needs to validate the cvv [Card Verification Value] using jquery. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The following errors have occurred.
(13) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive. be specific with Question !!

Comment: try the following regular expression /^[0-9]{3,4}$/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this function,

```
     function validate_cvv(cvv){

         var myRe = /^[0-9]{3,4}$/;
         var myArray = myRe.exec(cvv);
         if(cvv!=myArray)
          {
            alert("Invalid cvv number"); //invalid cvv number
            return false;
         }else{
             return true;  //valid cvv number
            }

         }
```

Comment: For Vista,Master card cvv is 3 digit,American express it is 4 digit.If you need to validate seperately, Modify var myRe seperately